# Glimpse - Only Seeing "Command: Executed" in Host Breakdown

Tags: asp.net, webforms, glimpse

We're running Glimpse.WebForms 1.1.1 and Glimpse.AspNet 1.9.2 on our test server within a Windows Azure Cloud Service, an extremely useful tool however we're getting a strange limitation.

When viewing the "Host" tab I can see a breakdown of the duration of command being called; however it gives no indication as to what "Command" is run.  See below:

[image: Command Executed]

Is there a way to get Glimpse to tell you which method is being run rather than stating "Command: Executed"?

Comment: This is really weird. It should show you the events in the page lifecycle and then the commands grouped (you shouldn't be seeing them as individual lines like this) under the relevant event they happened in. Do you know where these commands are being executed from (i.e. what event they are occurring in)?

Comment: In this instance it would be the result of a series of page_load and page_prerender events inside .aspx and .ascx files on the server side.